# fullCalendar - Scheduler - Business Hours for Multiple Resources

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar Scheduler and am trying to display the 'business hours' for a number of resources using inverse-background (to set a range when the resource is open and colour-code the other times to block them off)

The data is coming from a JSON Feed and is loading correctly.

Each 'business hours' event object is assigned to the correct resource.

The problem I am having is that the last event to render wipes all other events. This leaves only the hours for the final event. The rest are present (mouseover of the blocked-off region blocks 'select' of that time block) but not visible.

Additional notes:

- The business hours render properly in agendaWeek/agendaDay views.
- The issue is in timelineWeek/timelineDay views.
- Each resource has its own range of business hours.
- Setting each Event to have a unique ID doesn't seem to be helping - still doing a bit of digging with this...

Here is one of the returned event objects (null values have been removed for brevity):

- color: "red"
- end: "2016-04-17 20:00:00"
- eventType: 10
- flagForDelete: false
- id: "business hours1460654782"
- isNewRecord: true
- rendering: "inverse-background"
- resourceId: "12-29"
- start: "2016-04-17 13:00:00"
- title: "Sunday"
- updatePending: false

Am I missing something obvious?

Has anybody else managed to get something similar working?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!